# Intall virtualenv in vscode but fail

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I use windows 11，not sure why it gives me this error and how to fix it?

---

```
$ pip install virtualenv
>Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.16.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 8.8/8.8 MB 36.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00 
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.5
  Downloading distlib-0.3.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (466 kB)
     ------------------------------------ 467.0/467.0 KB 37.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00 
Collecting platformdirs<3,>=2.4
  Downloading platformdirs-2.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.4.1
  Downloading filelock-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: distlib, platformdirs, filelock, virtualenv
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\virtualenv.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\virtualenv.exe.deleteme'
```

Comment: Sorry I just find the answer.

More info here:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip

py -m pip --version
```
I updagrade the pip and it works afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There could be two possible reasons:**

**1)** Your pip version is outdated

**2)** Your windows user doesn't have the right permissions

so you could try the following commands to fix the issue:

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
pip install virtualenv --user
```

Note: Open command prompt with Run as Administrator